# Why is "autoreconf" not used often?

Tags: linux, autotools, autoreconf

I am newbie of [Autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Autotools). From my understanding, one would use the following basic steps to build software using Autotools:

1. `autoreconf --install`
2. `./configure`
3. `make`

However, I noticed that most open source software packages (on Linux) does not need the 1st step. Most of the time they just need step 2 and 3 to build. It seems that they already are packaged with a `Makefile.in`. I am wondering why? Do they manually code the `Makefile.in`, or does the software developer use `autoreconf` to generate the `Makefile.in` before creating the software package?

Comment: OK. I think I got a possible answer myself: by Not needing the user to run "autoreconf",  the software package puts less requirements on the end users' system. I.e. There is no need for the end user to have Autotools installed. I think this is actually quite big and good reason.

Comment: That's correct; when `configure` runs, all the user needs is a couple of script interpreters (a Bourne shell, sed, maybe perl too), plus the compiler toolchain. Even if all the library dependencies are missing, the `configure` script should be able to run and diagnose the problem or work around it. When you run `make dist-gzip`, you get a tarball with the `configure` script, plus all `*.in` template files packaged so the user doesn't have to do the previous steps that require autotools.

Answer (score 12):

The software developer who creates the tarball (or who checks out the sources from a version control system) will usually invoke `autoreconf` from a script called `bootstrap.sh` or `autogen.sh` which may do other stuff.  `autoreconf` might be invoked by `Makefile` as well (like when `configure.ac` has changed).

Most users will *never* need to run `autoreconf`, even those who are making some modifications to source (e.g. patches).  Only those who need to make modifications to the package itself (making changes to `configure.ac` and/or `Makefile.am`) will need `autoreconf`.

Answer (score 3):

Running `autoreconf` requires having the correct version of autotools installed already.  This leads to a chicken-and-egg problem -- how do you get autotools installed in the first place?  It also adds an extra dependency that most end-users don't really need.

As a result, *most* packagers run autoreconf before producing the source tarballs that they distribute.  This means that if you download such a tarball, you can configure and build it without needing to install autotools first.

Comment: If you want to bootstrap your system from source without using pre-generated `configure` scripts, then it's not impossible to install autotools directly without using autotools/configure (`autoconf` is just a shell script, you just need to replace a few placeholder variables that can be done with `sed`). And once you have one version of autotools, bootstrapping other versions is a bit easier.